# Angular 8 how to include json sublevel values ​in a table dropdown or repeat JSON 1st level values

Tags: angular, dropdown, angular8

Angular 8

Starting from JSON as repeating the values ​​of the 1st and 2nd column, being the third distinct Schedules: you can do this repetition passing each row to be unique.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC7r9.png)
In short the fields 1 and 2 in Json are unique, but I want to repeat, because the Schedule field has several Schedules and that with a click on the button GET perform the marcAction.

OR

Group as below, but I see the highest complexity level.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC1Fp.png)
* within a dropdown

Does anyone have any solution

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you are asking, but if you are asking how to organize data in the first screenshot (it would be very similiar for second screenshot), here it is:

```html
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Mary"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Tereza"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Joe"
    }
  ],
  "schedules": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "part": "Morning",
      "time": "08:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "part": "Afternoon",
      "time": "14:00"
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "type": "GET"
    }
  ],
  "entries": [
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "scheduleId": 1,
      "actionId": 1
    },
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "scheduleId": 2,
      "actionId": 1
    },
    {
      "userId": 2,
      "scheduleId": 1,
      "actionId": 1
    },
    {
      "userId": 3,
      "scheduleId": 1,
      "actionId": 1
    },
    {
      "userId": 4,
      "scheduleId": 1,
      "actionId": 1
    },
    {
      "userId": 4,
      "scheduleId": 2,
      "actionId": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

The idea is that you organize your data into small logical blocks and then entries are just combinations of those logical blocks. That way if you change a name of the person, you don't need to go all over the place and replace it.

And if you need to group it, then you can search for entries with the same userId or scheduleId, etc and group them that way.

I hope this helps. Good luck.